# Is it possible to use Session data in Laravel model? if possible than how?

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

**I am using Laravel version 6 and i wanna make the table name dynamic based on the Session data i have.How can i use the Session data in Laravel Model.**

Comment: How do you get the session value?? And what type of name of your model??

Comment: why not just create a table and then give two columns first `name` column for the name of the session you store and `data` column type `json` for session data.

Comment: Can it? It can. Should you? You shouldn't. Show controller where particular model is called. That place would be more appropriate.